# What is the efficient way to solve range query other than segment tree in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree

I am trying to understand segment trees. I tried a problem on hackerrank ([link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/source-code-series-1/challenges/sub-array-sum-range-query/problem)) and I tried to use the geeksforgeeks code in c++[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-range-minimum-query/). However, I got a dump value problem in line 19.

```
int right = RMQUtil(st, mid+1, se, qs, qe, 2*index+2); // why this is getting a dump value here?
```

Also I found that this is gonna time out. Is there an other efficient approach to solve this?
I want to know why my code is not efficient to solve this and need to have a better solution in c++

Here's the code I tried.

```
// you will see the comments on the geeksforgeeks code in the link. I used it here.

#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

int minVal(int x, int y) { return (x < y); }  
int getMid(int s, int e) { return s + (e -s)/2; } 

int RMQUtil(int *st, int ss, int se, int qs, int qe, int index) 
{ 
    if (qs <= ss && qe >= se) 
        return st[index]; 

    if (se < qs || ss > qe) 
        return INT_MAX; 

    int mid = getMid(ss, se);

    int left = RMQUtil(st, ss, mid, qs, qe, 2*index+1);
    int right = RMQUtil(st, mid+1, se, qs, qe, 2*index+2); // why this is getting a dump value here?
    return min({left, right, left+right},minVal); 
} 

int RMQ(int *st, int n, int qs, int qe) 
{ 

    if (qs < 0 || qe > n-1 || qs > qe) 
    { 
        cout<<"Invalid Input"; 
        return -1; 
    } 
    return RMQUtil(st, 0, n-1, qs, qe, 0); 
} 

int constructSTUtil(int arr[], int ss, int se, int *st, int si) 
{ 
    if (ss == se) 
    { 
        st[si] = arr[ss]; 
        return arr[ss]; 
    }  
    int mid = getMid(ss, se);
    int left = constructSTUtil(arr, ss, mid, st, si*2+1); 
    int right = constructSTUtil(arr, mid+1, se, st, si*2+2);
    st[si] = min({left, right, left+right},minVal); 
    return st[si]; 
}  

int *constructST(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    int x = (int)(ceil(log2(n)));  
    int max_size = 2*(int)pow(2, x) - 1; 

    int *st = new int[max_size];  
    constructSTUtil(arr, 0, n-1, st, 0); 
    return st; 
}
void updateSTUtil(int* st, int si, int ss, int se, int k, int v){
    if (k < ss or k > se)
        return;
    if (ss == se){
        st[si] = v;
        return;
        }
    int mid = getMid(ss, se);
    updateSTUtil(st, 2 * si +1, ss, mid, k, v);
    updateSTUtil(st, 2 * si +2, mid + 1, se, k, v);
    st[si] = min({st[2 * si +1], st[2 * si +2], st[2 * si +1] + st[2 * si +2]}, minVal);
}
void updateST(int n, int* st, int k, int v){
    updateSTUtil(st, 0, 0, n-1, k, v);  
    }

int main() 
{ 
    int t,n,q,a,ss,se;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for (int i=0; i<t; i++){
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int arr[n];
        for (int j=0 ; j<n; j++){
            cin >> arr[j];
        }
        int *st = constructST(arr, n);

        scanf("%d",&q);
        for (int i=0; i<q; i++){
            scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&ss,&se);
            if (a == 0){
                updateST(n, st, ss-1, se);
            }
            else{
                cout << RMQ(st, n, ss-1, se-1)<<endl;
            }
        }
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

:)

Comment: The wikipedia article outlines the best ways: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query

Comment: Out of curiosity, which C++ reference book says to use the non-portable `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?

Comment: BTW, `int arr[n];` is a *Variable Length Array (VLA)* and not standard C++.  Your compiler may have it as an extension.  Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Aren't effectively all compilers required to have that because it is a C99 standard and C++ compilers are supposed to compile C too?

Comment: @AlexGeorg that may have been true back in the early days, but by the 2000s the two languages had drifted too much. For example, see what happens if you use `auto` in C and then in modern C++

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks. I am new to c++. How can I use std::vector here?

Comment: I'd rather not instantiate tons of vectors inside of loops. That would not be efficient. Possibly requires major refactoring if you would really want to get rid of that statement. Wouldn't reccomend that unless your software is intended for  embedded hardware or such. Basically vectors appear very similar to arrays; they are just more convenient to use and store their memory on the heap instead of the stack (which is a downside if new vectors are requested often).

Comment: Alex has a good point here. The spec promises `n` is never greater than 50000, so assuming the target system offers an automatic data store of a megabyte or more (pretty much a given on a desktop system these days) `int arr[50000];` is probably the right solution. If automatic storage is an issue, you could make `arr` a global.

Comment: Even if you fix your timing issue your implementation is wrong and so you'll end up with wrong answers.

Comment: @Anatolii whats it and how to fix it?

Comment: @rusiruthushara I would suggest that you ask a different question first - "Does my solution produce a correct result?". This challenge is difficult and it requires significant effort in explaining why your solution is wrong and then suggesting an optimised solution.

Comment: @Anatolii could you please explain the reason?

Answer (score -1):

Check **Binary indexed tree or Fenwick tree** .

Check this

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-indexed-tree-range-update-range-queries/

And a
maybe interval tree according to what you want for eg. if you want to find maximum or minimum in range.

Comment: Thanks. why segment tree is not efficient here?

Comment: Segment tree time complexity have large constant factor. For more details check:

https://discuss.codechef.com/t/segment-tree-vs-bit/11469/3

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-segment-tree-and-a-Fenwick-tree-binary-index-tree

Comment: This answer needs a bit more meat to be a good answer. Currently is leans very heavily on an off-site link that will rot.